# Совместить 2 списка python

Tags: python

Имеется 2 списка:

```
lst_1 = ["qwe", "123", "qaz", "rtr"]
lst_2 = ["fff", "ert", "456", "lj"]
```

нужно получить это:

```
result = [["qwe", "fff"], ["123", "ert"], ["qaz", "456"], ["rtr", "lj"]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> lst_1 = ["qwe", "123", "qaz", "rtr"]
>>> lst_2 = ["fff", "ert", "456", "lj"]
>>> [list(pair) for pair in zip(lst_1, lst_2)]
[['qwe', 'fff'], ['123', 'ert'], ['qaz', '456'], ['rtr', 'lj']]
```